# Morris line do not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, morris.js

I'm trying to display a Morris line chart, but the line doesn't show up, like this

[image: screen shot of morris.line]

this is my code

```
 <div class="panel-body">
     <div id="morris_area_operation"></div>

     <?php 
           $operation_quey = DB::table('station_vehicule')
                    ->select('operation_date as date',
                            DB::raw('COUNT(operation_date) as nombre'))
                    ->where('operation_name', '=', 'Carburant')
                    ->groupBy('operation_date')
                    ->orderBy('operation_date', 'asc')
                    ->get();
     ?>

   <script>                     
       var data_collection = <?php echo json_encode($operation_quey); ?>;

       new Morris.Line({
           element: 'morris_area_operation',
           data: data_collection,
           xkey: 'date',
           ykeys: 'nombre',
           xLabelFormat: function(x) { 
                    return x.toDateString();
           },
           ymax: 'auto',
           hideHover: true,
           resize: true
           });
       </script>

 </div>
```

as you can see, the data exists (date and nombre) but i can't see the line in the chart

help mplease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ykeys` should be an array:

```
ykeys: ['nombre'],
```

([working jsFiddle based on your example](https://jsfiddle.net/67b205x2/))

See [the documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html):

> **ykeys (required):** A list of strings containing names of attributes that contain Y values (one for each series of data to be plotted).